# Can I enable Power over Ethernet from a MacBook Pro?

Tags: ip, phone, power-over-ethernet

I've recently gotten a Cisco IP telephone. I've an Macbook Pro (15", Late 2011): Is there any way to enable PoE to test my phone?

Or do I have to buy an extra PoE injector just for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry. No.

You need a power injector *or* a PoE switch *or* a power adapter for the phone.